# Is Hanekawa punching Hachikuji out of character?

Tags: monogatari-series

When Hachikuji was first introduced in *Bakemonogatari*, there was this scene where Hanekawa punched Hachikuji. I feel that's pretty out of character especially after seeing more of her personality in the later part of the series. I took it as just a comic relief.

In *Nisemonogatari*, however, Hanekawa stopped Araragi from hitting Karen when Karen got reckless.

Are there other evidences showing that Hanekawa punching Hachikuji is not out of character?

Comment: Hi. What episode was this? I could not remember Hanekawa punching Hachikuji. If I recall correctly, wasn't Hachikuji with Araragi in most of her scenes since he's the only one who can see her?

Comment: Just realized this is only in the light novel, but in the anime Hanekawa only lightly knocked Hachikuji's head. I guess it is out of character after all.

Comment: Okay. I have not yet read the light novel (only seen the anime) so I'll defer to people who might be able to provide a better answer :) It just surprised me because I could only recall Araragi being physical with Hachikuji, and he was one of those, if not the only one, she interacted with a lot.

Comment: Right, but Hanekawa in ep 4 can see Hachkuji, partly because she does not want to go home that day.

Comment: Hanekawa also smacks Hachikuji in ch. 12, in the same scene. I'm assuming this was supposed to be a light smack to reprimand her, rather than a "punch," but I don't remember the scene in _Nisemonogatari_ so don't have a good point of comparison.